# Is the Type-safe Enum pattern still viable in C# version 6+

Tags: c#

I recently came back to the .NET world after a few years on JVM/Groovy territory.

One of my favorite day-to-day patterns in C# used to be the [Type-Safe enum pattern](https://blog.falafel.com/introducing-type-safe-enum-pattern/), which I find very handy. Coming back to C# I immediately started using it, but now I suspect that there might be better, or more preferable patterns.

What got me thinking was that I want to introduce some behaviour in the "enums". Like this:

```
public sealed class TypeSafeEnumWithBehaviour
{
    public static readonly TypeSafeEnumWithBehaviour IsLowerCase = new TypeSafeEnumWithBehaviour("IsLowerCase", s => s.All(c => Char.IsLower(c)));
    public static readonly TypeSafeEnumWithBehaviour IsUpperCase = new TypeSafeEnumWithBehaviour("IsUpperCase", s => s.All(c => Char.IsUpper(c)));

    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly Func<string, bool> IsValid;

    private TypeSafeEnumWithBehaviour(string targetName, Func<string, bool> validation)
    {
        Name = targetName;
        IsValid = validation;
    }

}
```

Tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(TypeSafeEnumWithBehaviour.IsLowerCase.IsValid("apa"));
    Assert.IsTrue(TypeSafeEnumWithBehaviour.IsUpperCase.IsValid("PAPA"));
}
```

My organization is currently using C# 6, but C# 7 is becoming more prevalent which led me to several questions.

1. What is the current view of the type-safe enum pattern?
2. Is it still a valid pattern, especially with regards to
   serialization/persistation?
3. Should I abandon it in favour something else?

Comment: The link is perhaps not the most authorative, but i think it explains the pattern well

Comment: From my perspective, if you want to take enums to next level it's better to model them as value objects or some enumeration classes. I know it looks strange at 1st sight but at least you can take a look: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/

Comment: I've used this pattern in the past, but I don't really consider them "enums".  I haven't seen anything in the upcoming language versions that offers functionality like this, so it seems like it is still a valid pattern.

Comment: You could get [lazy](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization) with the initialization if you want, but other than that, it still seems to be a nice pattern for what you're using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# (as of version 7.1) does not support [sum types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), so until this is resolved, the pattern described in the link you provided applies as a partial solution to the *statically-checked close-world variants* problem. You can check how proper language support for this look like in [F#](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/).

Your example is slightly strange: those options are not really distinct variants. For `""`, they both hold, for `"Aa"` neither of them holds. They really do not form a collection of distinct possibilities, so it's not clear why to call them enums.

Minor nitpick unrelated to C# 7 language innovations: you should consider is using `nameof` like this:

`public static readonly TypeSafeEnumWithBehaviour IsLowerCase = new TypeSafeEnumWithBehaviour(nameof(IsLowerCase), s => s.All(c => Char.IsLower(c)));`

Comment: You should be explicit that `nameof` comes from `c# 6`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're trying to do with the enum.

In your example where you want to check the case, perhaps an extension method would be appropriate like so:

```
public static bool IsLowerCase(this Enum value)
{
    return value.ToString() == value.ToString().ToLower();
}
```

This would allow you to use it like so:

```
SomeEnum value = SomeEnums.Test;
if (value.IsLowerCase())
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

To answer your questions:

- The type-safe enum pattern is still valid in some scenarios where you might not want extension methods or other approaches.
- Serialization may best be done via attributes but any instance needs to be taken on a case by case basis - it's too general to give blanket advice.
- Only abandon it where there's a clear case to be made for doing so, e.g., new language features, etc. This holds true when using any pattern really.